# connections with circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, node-connections

I'm trying to create a diagram from motor controller consisting of a microcontroller and its peripherals.

1) How to get the red dot on the line with circuitikz.
2) Draw current arrow below the resistor with Im at the right.

Kindly look at the diagram below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,backgrounds, calc, fit}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{peripheral} = [draw, fill=blue!10, rectangle, minimum height=3em,
text width=6em, align = flush center, rounded corners, thick, drop shadow]

\tikzstyle{micro} = [draw, fill=green!10, rectangle, minimum height=7em, minimum
width = 8em, rounded corners, thick, drop shadow] 

\tikzstyle{motor} = [draw, fill=yellow!10, circle, radius=2cm, thick, drop shadow] 
\tikzstyle{motorConnector} = [draw, fill=black, rectangle, draw=black, inner sep=1mm];

\tikzstyle{line1} = [draw, thick, ->, shorten >= 1pt, >=stealth']
\tikzstyle{line2} = [draw, thick, <->, shorten >= 1pt, shorten <=1pt, >=stealth'] 
\tikzstyle{line3} = [draw, thick, shorten >=1pt]
\tikzstyle{line4} = [draw, line width=5pt , shorten >=1pt]

%beginning tikz
\begin{tikzpicture} [auto, node distance = 1cm, >=latex', background
  rectangle/.style= {fill=yellow!10, draw=blue!15, rounded corners=1ex}, show
  background rectangle, circuitikz]

 \matrix [column sep = 1cm, row sep = 0.5cm] at (0,0)
 {
   \node [peripheral] (timer) {Timers}; &
   \node [peripheral] (rtc) {RTC}; &
   \node [peripheral] (watchdog) {Watch Dog}; &\\
   %row 2
   \node [peripheral] (comm) {Serial \\Interface}; &
   \node [micro] (cpu) {CPU}; &
   \node [peripheral] (dac) {DAC}; &\\
   %row 3
   \node [peripheral] (pwm) {PWM Timer}; &
   \node [peripheral] (adc) {ADC}; & 
   \node [peripheral] (qdec) {Quadrature \\ Decoder}; &\\
   %row5
   \node [peripheral, yshift=-1.5cm] {Motor Driver};&
   \node {};&
   \node {};&\\
   %row6
   \node {};&
   \node [xshift = -1cm, motor] (motor) {Motor};&\\
   \node {};&\\
 };

 \node [draw=black, inner sep= 0.75cm, fit={(timer) (qdec) (pwm)}, rounded
 corners=1ex, thick, fill=black!20, opacity=0.1]  (motorController) {};
 \node [yshift = -0.30cm, thick] at (motorController.north) {\large$Motor Controller$};

 \node [motorConnector] at (motor.north) (connector1) {};
 \node [motorConnector] at (motor.south) (connector2) {};

 \draw (connector2.south) to [R=$R_I$] +(0,-3)
       [red, *-] {($(connector2.south) + (0,-0.5)$) -| (adc.south)} ;


 \node [ground] at ($(connector2.south) + (0,-3)$) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: motor controller]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a possible solution where modification are near the end of this code.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,backgrounds, calc, fit}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{peripheral} = [draw, fill=blue!10, rectangle, minimum height=3em,
text width=6em, align = flush center, rounded corners, thick, drop shadow]

\tikzstyle{micro} = [draw, fill=green!10, rectangle, minimum height=7em, minimum
width = 8em, rounded corners, thick, drop shadow] 

\tikzstyle{motor} = [draw, fill=yellow!10, circle, radius=2cm, thick, drop shadow] 
\tikzstyle{motorConnector} = [draw, fill=black, rectangle, draw=black, inner sep=1mm];

\tikzstyle{line1} = [draw, thick, ->, shorten >= 1pt, >=stealth']
\tikzstyle{line2} = [draw, thick, <->, shorten >= 1pt, shorten <=1pt, >=stealth'] 
\tikzstyle{line3} = [draw, thick, shorten >=1pt]
\tikzstyle{line4} = [draw, line width=5pt , shorten >=1pt]

%beginning tikz
\begin{tikzpicture} [auto, node distance = 1cm, >=latex', background
  rectangle/.style= {fill=yellow!10, draw=blue!15, rounded corners=1ex}, show
  background rectangle, circuitikz]

 \matrix [column sep = 1cm, row sep = 0.5cm] at (0,0)
 {
   \node [peripheral] (timer) {Timers}; &
   \node [peripheral] (rtc) {RTC}; &
   \node [peripheral] (watchdog) {Watch Dog}; &\\
   %row 2
   \node [peripheral] (comm) {Serial \\Interface}; &
   \node [micro] (cpu) {CPU}; &
   \node [peripheral] (dac) {DAC}; &\\
   %row 3
   \node [peripheral] (pwm) {PWM Timer}; &
   \node [peripheral] (adc) {ADC}; & 
   \node [peripheral] (qdec) {Quadrature \\ Decoder}; &\\
   %row5
   \node [peripheral, yshift=-1.5cm] {Motor Driver};&
   \node {};&
   \node {};&\\
   %row6
   \node {};&
   \node [xshift = -1cm, motor] (motor) {Motor};&\\
   \node {};&\\
 };

 \node [draw=black, inner sep= 0.75cm, fit={(timer) (qdec) (pwm)}, rounded
 corners=1ex, thick, fill=black!20, opacity=0.1]  (motorController) {};
 \node [yshift = -0.30cm, thick] at (motorController.north) {\large$Motor Controller$};

 \node [motorConnector] at (motor.north) (connector1) {};
 \node [motorConnector] at (motor.south) (connector2) {};

 %%%-- some modification starts here

 \draw (connector2.south) to [R=$R_I$] +(0,-3)
{($(connector2.south) + (0,-0.5)$) -| (adc.south)} 
      [red,*-] {($(connector2.south) + (0,-0.46)$)};     %< -- the red node
\node [ground] at ($(connector2.south) + (0,-3)$) {};
\draw[red,->] ($(connector2.south)+(0,-2.2)$) to [] +(0,-0.5)node[right]{$I=1mA$}; %<--the current arrow
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please explain me, `\draw[red,->] ($(connector2.south)+(0,-2.2)$) to [] +(0,-0.5)node[right]{$I=1mA$};` especially `[] +(0,-0.5)`.

Comment: Yes, it means `starting from ($(connector2.south)+(0,-2.2)$) which is the lower edge of R1 box, draw a line downward 0.5cm, and put a node having a text of 1mA.

Comment: to [option] +(0,-0.5) -- `to [option]` is similar to `edge[option]`  in syntax structure. The + in +(x,y) means add (x,y) (here (0,-0.5) means vertically downward 0.5cm due to -) to the previous point and take it as the end point because a line with an arrow is drawn in red. In you case the previous point is the coordinate ($ ...... $) right before `to[]`.

Comment: I was wondering why the picture is not center aligned though I have used `align center` at `\begin{tikzpicture}`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @raman-- I am not sure I understand your problem, because I don't see `align center` in the OP. However, my wild guess is that you want to move the `MotorController` box to the center (a little bit to the right). If this is true, then add `xshift=0.5cm` to the [option] of node of `MotorController`, which is right below the `\matrix` node.

Comment: thanks for the responses. The reason for the misalignment is due to the matrix. It looks as if adds extra space to the right of the matrix. I added an empty first element in each row of the matrix to solve it.